# How to pass element from model in ajax post request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

First of all sorry for my English.

I have no idea how to upload element from the model (var nameData in )using AJAX . I asked for a hint, here is the code:

View:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in (Model.files))
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4>@item</h4>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="sendCodesToDB" class="btn btn-success" value="Insert codes in DB" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

and script:

```
<script>
$('#sendCodesToDB').on('click', function () {

    var nameData = //Here I am trying to put: @item.Name;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Foo',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: nameData,
        success: function (dataFromAction) {
            $('#idTextu').val(dataFromAction);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to apply your tips, my code now:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertCodesToDB(string name)
    {
        cl.InsertCodesToDB(name);
        fl.MoveCodeFileToAccept(name);

        string response = "Test";
        return Content(response, "application/json");  
    }
```

View:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success sendCodesToDB" value="Insert Codes in DB" data-value="@item.Name"/>
```

Script:

```
$('.sendCodesToDB').on('click', function () {

    var name = $(this).data("value");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ActualCodes/InsertCodesToDB',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: name,
        success: function (response) {
             @(ViewBag.MessageOK) = response;
        },
        error: function () {
            onBegin;
        }
    });
});
```

But unfortunately the currently pressing button sendCodesToDB dont work. I caught up in Controller and Action is not called. 
Where I have problem ?

Comment: try to use any plugin of jquery for this propouse, is too easy to implement https://www.google.es/search?q=jquery+upload&oq=jquery+upload+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3888j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: You need to have that value on an actual element to be able to get it. You can use `data-*` attributes, hidden input etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you shouldn't be using same id in loop. Remove id attribute and make id as class like below:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success sendCodesToDB" value="Insert codes in DB" />
```

And change your javascript code like this:

```
<script>
$('.sendCodesToDB').on('click', function () {

var nameData = $(this).parent().prev().text();

$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Foo',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify( { nameData :  nameData}),
    success: function (dataFromAction) {
        $('#idTextu').val(dataFromAction);
    }
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies. They are all very helpful and learning.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make an hidden input or data-atribute and get the value out of it.

```
<input id="itemname" type="hidden" value="@item.name">
```

or

```
<div id="itemname" data-name="@item.name"></div>
```

You can get the value out of it trough JQuery.

```
var nameData = $("#itemname").val();
```

With data-atribute

```
var nameData = $("#itemname").data("name");
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies. They are all very helpful and learning.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this is possibly adding the value (item.Name) as a data attribute to the input.

```
<input type="button" id="sendCodesToDB" class="btn btn-success" value="Insert codes in DB" data-value="@item.Name" />
```

Then in the jQuery

```
var nameData = $(this).data("value");
```

I would also suggest using a class on the input, as elements with the same Id will not work properly. i.e.

```
<input class="sendCodesToDb" />
```

jQuery

```
$(".sendCodesToDb").on("click", function(){ ... });
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies. They are all very helpful and learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `hidden` input for this case and put it just before the button, now you will be able to get the value of that hidden input using `$(this).prev('.item_name').val()`:

```js
$('.sendCodesToDB').on('click', function () {

    var nameData = $(this).prev('.item_name').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Foo',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: nameData,
        success: function (dataFromAction) {
            $('#idTextu').val(dataFromAction);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in (Model.files))
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4>@item</h4>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class='item_name' type='hidden' value='@item.Name'>
                <input type="button" class="sendCodesToDB btn btn-success" value="Insert codes in DB" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Also, ids have to be unique, now you don't have an unique id on your button, I recommend you to add a class on it and target that on click. I changed your code a bit to fix this part.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. They are all very helpful and learning.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use stringify when passing data in jQuery Ajax call

$.ajax({

```
    type: post or get,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: strURL,
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({ DocumentIDs: DocumentIDList, IsShowLayers: isShowLayers }),
    success: function (data) {},
    error: FailureCallBack
});
```